# App binary rejection because of missing storyboard file?

Tags: iphone, xcode, binary

I got this email from Apple:

> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "App Name Here". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
>   Missing Storyboard File - The referenced storyboard file 'Pass_iPhone.storyboard.storyboardc' was not found in the application bundle.

I don't understand the issue, my storyboard is visible in my project and is editable ect? What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is your problem, but one thing to check: With the storyboard file selected in the Xcode Project Navigator on the left side, click on the File Inspector tab in the Utilities panel on the right side and make sure your storyboard file has the check box selected for your project under Target Membership. If it is not selected, the file will not be included in the app bundle, although it will still be editable.

Comment: Yeah I just check, its ticked. Thanks anyway, for future reference what should the status of an app be when its been uploaded for review?

Comment: I also have Localization set as English should this option been selected?

Comment: YES! My app is waiting for review. I had to rename my storyboard file then update name everywhere in the project. Just as well I sorted it nobody else seems to have experienced this!